# struct as a type for function in C++

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and am trying to create a function with a return type of "my_message_t" that was defined in the class definition. However when I tried to compile it, compiler informed me that error: **‘my_message_t’ does not name a type**

I have the following code (protocols.h and protocols.cpp)

```
    namespace Protocols {
                class Messages {
                    public:

                        typedef struct _my_message_t {
                            //stuffs
                        } my_message_t;

                        typedef enum {
                                //stuffs 
                        } my_message_e;

                private:
                    my_message_t                            my_msg;
                    my_message_e                            msg_en; 

                public:
                    Messages();     
                    ~Messages();    

                    my_message_t create_message(const my_message__e); 

            };
        };
```

with the class definition is below:

```
            namespace Protocols {

                    Messages::Messages(){
                        //stuff
                    };

                    Messages::~Messages(){
                        //stuffs
                    }

                    my_message_t Messages::create_message(my_message_e type){
                        my_message_t msg;

                        //do stuffs

                        return msg;
                    }
            }
```

Why I can not create a function with a type of `my_message_t` ? How do I fix that code above?

Comment: `Messages::my_message_t`?

Comment: By the way, in C++ there's no need for the `struct/typedef` trick, you should avoid it.

Comment: You don't need `typedef` for structures. In C++ the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that in `struct` the default visibility is `public` and in class it's `private`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`my_message_t` is scoped inside the `Messages` class, so it needs to be qualified when used outside a member of the class:

```
Messages::my_message_t Messages::create_message(my_message_e type){
^^^^^^^^^^
    // do stuffs
}
```

Note that you don't need that in the function parameter list, only the return type; a quirk of the language means that the parameter list is scoped inside the function, and the return type outside.

Comment: I do not speak good english, can you please elaborate more the sentence of "you don't need that in the function parameter list, only the return type; a quirk of the language means that the parameter list is scoped inside the function, and the return type outside." ?

Comment: @xambo: You need `Messages::` on `my_message_t` (the function's *return type*), because that's technically outside the function. You don't need it on `my_message_e` (the function's *parameter*), because that's technically inside the function. Inside the function, all class members are available without needing `::`.

Comment: tried to remove the Messages:: before my_message_e , it does not compile saying that my_message_e is unknown type. But after I add Messages:my_message_e type on parameter, everything compiles just fine..

Comment: @xambo: The code you've posted has a typo: there's a double underscore in `my_message_e` in the function declaration. If you fix that, then it should compile with or without `Messages::`. At least, it does for me.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
my_message_t Messages::create_message(my_message_type_e type)
```

to:

```
Messages::my_message_t Messages::create_message(my_message_e type)
^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

`my_message_t` is a type defined inside of class `Messages`, so you need:

```
Messages::my_message_t Messages::create_message(my_message_type_e type)
```